# No me deja filtrar campos si tengo alguno NULL

Tags: angular

cuando intento filtrar campos si algún campo de mi base de datos está en NULL no puedo filtrar por ese campo.

Para poder filtrar debo de dejarlos vacíos, osea quitar el NULL y entonces ya sí me deja filtrar por todos los campos que le pongo

Alguna idea de por que me sucede eso?

```
   import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
   import { PacientesComponent } from '../components/pacientes/pacientes.component';


    @Pipe({
      name: 'pacientesfilter'
    })
    export class PacientesfilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
      constructor(public pacientComp:PacientesComponent){

      }
      transform(items:any, filterApellido: string, filterDni: string, filterHistoria: string){
        if (items && items.length){
            return items.filter(item =>{
                if (filterApellido && item.apellidos.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterApellido.toLowerCase()) === -1){
                    return false;
                }
                if (filterDni && item.dni.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterDni.toLowerCase()) === -1){
                    return false;
                }
                if (filterHistoria && item.historia.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterHistoria.toLowerCase()) === -1){
                    return false;
                }


                return true;
            })
        }
        else{
            return items;
        }

    }
}
```

Este es mi código para filtrar